# Can one use a keyfile as a password for sudo?

Tags: sudo, usb, usb-drive

## Context

I like to work in public on my laptop, but I also like to use sudo without a password.  Based on what I know now, I would use the `NOPASSWD` option in my `sudoers` file, but of course anyone could use sudo as they wish.

**One important thought** that comes to my mind **is that locking programs exist.**  However, I would prefer using a flash drive (and using it just for sudo) because (1) it is faster, (2) easier than entering my password, and (3) I am not concerned with people accessing my content nor doing nefarious things: the laptop would be in public around other people, and the only intellectual property on my laptop is a very basic Angular project.

Additionally, myself and others may wish to prevent misuse of sudo on a computer not running an X or Wayland environment.  My current work requires a modern web browser, but if I ever have the chance to not use X and just use a multiplexer, I do that -- my laptop is a bit old and slow.

## Question

What I would like to do is put a keyfile on a flash drive, and simply plug in the flash drive when I am at the laptop, and take it out when I step away from it.

So here are my three questions derived from this problem:

1. Is this possible with sudo as is?
2. If not, would I be able to write a program that lets me do this?
3. If so, what language might be the best to write this program?

(4. [Perhaps an extraneous question] Could this package be separate or would it need to be a fork of sudo?)

#### Note

If it is relevant, my setup is Arch Linux with bspwm, no desktop environment.  Most of my work is web development in urxvt / vim and checking it with Chrome.

Comment: Does [pam_usb](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pam_usb) meet your needs?

Comment: @StrongBad Oh...yep.  It looks like it doesn't immediately do *just* sudo, and does login and sudo together, but that doesn't matter to me.  Thanks!

Comment: Okay, to clarify, you want to stay logged in constantly and just prevent people from using sudo under your account.

Comment: @StrongBad Correct.

Comment: You might be able to configure something using the `rootpw` flag in the `/etc/sudoers` files and setting up `pam_usb` for root login.

Comment: I just noticed the comment by @StrongBad. It wasn't at all clear to me from the post that you intended for other people to be able to use your account. I don't understand why you need or want this, but if that's really what you're going for you might want to update your post to include a more explicit statement, e.g. "I want to stay constantly logged in, I want this account to have `sudo` privileges, and I want other people to be able to use my account, but I don't want them to be able to run `sudo`).

Comment: If you could add some explanation of why the usual solution of switching to an administrative account doesn't work for you that would also be helpful. Is typing in a password once really that much of an inconvenience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand why the `NOPASSWD` option doesn't satisfy your requirements all by itself, but if you want to require the presence of the flash drive I can think of something that might almost do what you're looking for.

This is more of a workaround, but you could create a local administrative user, say `superuser`, and give that user passwordless `sudo` rights, i.e. add the following line to your `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
superuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

You could then disable password login and configure key-only SSH authentication for that user, i.e. run `passwd -l superuser` and add the following stanza to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match user superuser
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Then create an SSH key-pair for this user. Add the public key to `/home/superuser/.ssh/authorized_keys` and put the private key on your flash drive. Then when you want to use the `superuser` account, plug in your flash-drive and ssh into the `superuser` account using your private key. And voilà! You now have passwordless `sudo` for your user. Of course you'll still need to exit your shell sessions when you're done - unplugging the flash drive won't be enough. Although I guess you could also setup a [precommand hook](https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command) to check for the private key and exit automatically if it isn't present (or if it's invalid).

Comment: an easy answer to clear up as to why you might want to do this.  for this server im trying to get back into, i only have the root key, no root ssh access, im locked into the ec2-user,  which sudo is asking a pw i dont have.  i scp'd my root key to the server, so i would ideally now like to use this key to gain sudo acces, then i can fix things.